# Typescript get Int8Array from ArrayBuffer

Tags: typescript, uint8array

I'm reading a file as ArrayBuffer with this code:

```
 var reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    var fileContent = reader.result;
    ...
 }
```

I need to get the content as byte array but I can't do it. 
If I try to convert in this way:

```
var byteArray = new Int8Array(fileContent);
```

I get this error: impossible to assign string to ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike | SharedArrayBuffer. 
Is fileContent a string? I think it should be an ArrayBuffer because I'm using readAsArrayBuffer.
Is there a way to get byte array from uploaded file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add type assertion

```
var byteArray = new Int8Array(fileContent as ArrayBuffer);
```